# Is there any reason why this song is written entirely in kanji?

Tags: kanji

I was looking up the lyrics for the song 反面教師為貴方覇本日怒上昇中乃巻 by 久保あおい ([youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CpV4dnKv0E)), and I noticed that the lyrics are entirely in kanji. I thought that was interesting since its a song, not writing, so I thought that nobody would be able to tell that they wrote it entirely in kanji. Would a fluent listener easily notice the song is written entirely in kanji by just listening, and does it flow unnaturally because its written in such a weird way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [the lyrics](https://utaten.com/lyric/rq21040606/), most of them are not proper sentences, more of arrays of words. Also in some places, there are 当て字 (use of phonetic equivalent) like "地獄覇", where 覇 is used as a kanji for the normal particle は.

So just a plain listener won't think that it is written entirely kanji. It is weird more because there are not many sentences that make sense. I guess it is mimicking Buddhist mantras.